# Emulator does not show anything

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, console

Console is display the following comments.but In the emulator required application doesn't show anything.

```
[2013-07-20 12:09:41 - searchdb] Android Launch!
[2013-07-20 12:09:41 - searchdb] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-20 12:09:41 - searchdb] Performing com.example.searchdb.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-07-20 12:09:41 - searchdb] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Api17' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-20 12:09:46 - searchdb] Uploading searchdb.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-20 12:09:46 - searchdb] Installing searchdb.apk...
[2013-07-20 12:10:00 - searchdb] Success!
[2013-07-20 12:10:01 - searchdb] Starting activity com.example.searchdb.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```

This is the logcat file.This same issue for alll the projects in my workspace.I have a problem with avd, so that I never proceed my projects.please help me to solve the issue.Thanks in Advance.

Logcat file

```
07-20 07:13:42.034: E/System(11988): ******************************************
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988): ************ Failure starting core service
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 95 to 94
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4820)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4430)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installSystemProviders(ActivityThread.java:4968)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.installSystemProviders(ActivityManagerService.java:6898)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:282)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 95 to 94
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.establishDbTracking(SettingsProvider.java:386)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.onCreate(SettingsProvider.java:326)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4817)
07-20 07:13:42.114: E/System(11988):    ... 4 more
07-20 07:13:42.114: I/SystemServer(11988): Input Method Service
07-20 07:13:42.454: W/InputMethodManagerService(11988): Couldn't create dir.: /data/system/inputmethod
07-20 07:13:42.626: D/ActivityThread(11988): Loading provider settings: com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider
07-20 07:13:43.634: W/SystemServer(11988): ***********************************************
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988): BOOT FAILURE starting Input Manager Service
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 95 to 94
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4820)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4471)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1987)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1085)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.lazyGetProvider(Settings.java:749)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:796)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getStringForUser(Settings.java:2757)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService$InputMethodSettings.getSelectedInputMethod(InputMethodManagerService.java:3832)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.<init>(InputMethodManagerService.java:669)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:361)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 95 to 94
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.establishDbTracking(SettingsProvider.java:386)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.onCreate(SettingsProvider.java:326)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4817)
07-20 07:13:43.666: A/SystemServer(11988):  ... 9 more
07-20 07:13:43.866: I/SystemServer(11988): Accessibility Manager
07-20 07:13:44.056: W/SystemServer(11988): ***********************************************
07-20 07:13:44.056: A/SystemServer(11988): BOOT FAILURE making display ready
07-20 07:13:44.056: A/SystemServer(11988): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 07:13:44.056: A/SystemServer(11988):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:377)
07-20 07:13:44.095: W/dalvikvm(11988): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5e2f908)
07-20 07:13:44.095: E/AndroidRuntime(11988): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
07-20 07:13:44.095: E/AndroidRuntime(11988): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 07:13:44.095: E/AndroidRuntime(11988):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.showBootMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:4353)
07-20 07:13:44.095: E/AndroidRuntime(11988):    at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:389)
```

This is my manifest file
Manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.searchdb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.searchdb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my main activity class:
main activity:

```java
package com.example.searchdb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        protected EditText searchText;
        protected SQLiteDatabase db;
        protected Cursor cursor;
        protected ListAdapter adapter;
        protected ListView employeeList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        employeeList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                                                new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                this, 
                                R.layout.list_item, 
                                cursor, 
                                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                                new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
                employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

This is another class for using sqlite database:
DatabaseHelper.java:

```java
package com.example.searchdb;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_directory";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                /*
                 * Create the employee table and populate it with sample data.
                 * In step 6, we will move these hardcoded statements to an XML document.
                 */
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (" +
                                                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                                                "firstName TEXT, " +
                                                "lastName TEXT, " +
                                                "title TEXT, " +
                                                "officePhone TEXT, " +
                                                "cellPhone TEXT, " +
                                                "email TEXT, " +
                                                "managerId INTEGER)";
                db.execSQL(sql);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put("firstName", "John");
                values.put("lastName", "Smith");
                values.put("title", "CEO");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2001");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-456-7890");
                values.put("email", "jsmith@email.com");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Robert");
                values.put("lastName", "Jackson");
                values.put("title", "VP Engineering");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-3333");
                values.put("cellPhone", "781-444-2222");
                values.put("email", "rjackson@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "1");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Marie");
                values.put("lastName", "Potter");
                values.put("title", "VP Sales");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2002");
                values.put("cellPhone", "987-654-3210");
                values.put("email", "mpotter@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "1");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Lisa");
                values.put("lastName", "Jordan");
                values.put("title", "VP Marketing");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2003");
                values.put("cellPhone", "987-654-7777");
                values.put("email", "ljordan@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Christophe");
                values.put("lastName", "Coenraets");
                values.put("title", "Evangelist");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-0000");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-666-7777");
                values.put("email", "ccoenrae@adobe.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Paula");
                values.put("lastName", "Brown");
                values.put("title", "Director Engineering");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-612-0987");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-123-9876");
                values.put("email", "pbrown@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

                values.put("firstName", "Mark");
                values.put("lastName", "Taylor");
                values.put("title", "Lead Architect");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-444-1122");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-555-3344");
                values.put("email", "mtaylor@email.com");
                values.put("managerId", "2");
                db.insert("employee", "lastName", values);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
                onCreate(db);
        }

}
```

Comment: Please post your Manifest and MainActivity

Comment: r u debuging application from command prompt?

Comment: Make your emulator stop saving its snapshot. That should clear the error right up.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is really the solution, but I got into some problems with my AVD after editing some of its settings (including API level) instead of deleting and creating a new one.

I was indeed getting the "can't downgrade database from version 95 to 94" error you mentioned and the avd would not even launch.

After deleting and creating a new avd, the problem seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your like doesn't have quite the correct syntax.  I would try:

```
 + " LIKE \"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%\""
```

In addition, I'm confused why you have 'LIKE ?' and not just 'LIKE', since I'm assuming the value of 'searchText.getText().toString()' is what you are searching on.  If this is the correct case then then you can pass null for the where arguments also.

Hope this helps.